# Google Script Only Reads Frst Few Lines

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script

I want the monitorEmails function to find new messages in the Inbox. For whatever reason, GS does not read past the first two lines of code, I know this because the Log only shows the first

```
Logger.log(..)
```

statement has been verified.  GS only logs the first few lines and doesn't give any feedback beyond the first statement.

How can I get GS to show the Logger.log(..) statements?

Here's code:

```
    //set a time-driven trigger to run this function on the desired frequency
function monitorEmails() {  
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox 
  // log the number of messages in the thread
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var numMsgs = firstThread.getMessageCount();  // # of messages in a given thread
  Logger.log(firstThread.getMessageCount());
  var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
  if (firstThread.isUnread()=='true'){  // check if thread is Read
    //Logger.log(firstThread.isUnread()=='true');
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {  //Go through each message within a   Thread
      // Logger.log(messages[i].getSubject());
      if (messages[i].isUnread()){   // if the message is unread
        Logger.log(messages[i].isUnread());
        var unreadBody = messages[i].getBody();  // Body contents variable that contains the body 
        Logger.log(messages[i].getBody());
        var unreadFrom = messages[i].getFrom();  // Email Sender contents variable
        //Logger.log(messages[i].getFrom());
        messages[i].markRead();  // Mark message as read
        //Logger.log(messages[i].markRead());  
        var fullLot = "Full";  // look for "Full" in text message.
        //Logger.log(unreadBody.search(fullLot) =='true');
        if(unreadBody.search(fullLot) == 'true' && getEmail()==AdminTest()){
          // if the sender has the proper admin email / phone #, then call function sendEmails
          sendEmails();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a problem in comparisons like this:

```
if (firstThread.isUnread()=='true'){  // check if thread is Read
```

You are comparing a Boolean to a String. Both `true` and `false` are keywords, so they should not be enclosed in quotes:

```
if (firstThread.isUnread() == true){  // check if thread is Read
```

In a couple of places, you're performing a comparison, then logging the result of the comparison inside the `if` block - it's more useful to log that before the comparison.

I think you'd help yourself out by making your logs more meaningful, with some context information - the modified script shows examples of this.

#### Logs

```
[13-07-02 09:40:53:583 EDT] numMsgs=1
[13-07-02 09:40:53:583 EDT] Subject=YOU could be our Player of the Week!
[13-07-02 09:40:53:658 EDT] firstThread.isUnread()==true
[13-07-02 09:40:53:658 EDT] messages[0].subject=YOU could be our Player of the Week!
[13-07-02 09:40:53:658 EDT] messages[0].isUnread=true
...
```

#### Modified script

```
function monitorEmails() {  
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox 
  // log the number of messages in the thread
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var numMsgs = firstThread.getMessageCount();  // # of messages in a given thread
  Logger.log("numMsgs="+numMsgs);
  Logger.log("Subject="+firstThread.getFirstMessageSubject());
  var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
  Logger.log("firstThread.isUnread()=="+firstThread.isUnread());
  if (firstThread.isUnread()== true ){  // check if thread is Read
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {  //Go through each message within a   Thread
      Logger.log("messages["+i+"].subject="+messages[i].getSubject());
      Logger.log("messages["+i+"].isUnread="+messages[i].isUnread());
      if (messages[i].isUnread()){   // if the message is unread
        var unreadBody = messages[i].getBody();  // Body contents variable that contains the body 
        Logger.log("messages["+i+"].body="+unreadBody);
        var unreadFrom = messages[i].getFrom();  // Email Sender contents variable
        Logger.log("messages["+i+"].from="+messages[i].getFrom());
        messages[i].markRead();  // Mark message as read
        Logger.log("messages["+i+"].isUnread="+messages[i].isUnread()); 
        var fullLot = "Full";  // look for "Full" in text message.
        var searchResult = unreadBody.search(fullLot);
        Logger.log("messages["+i+"].searchResult="+searchResult);
        if(searchResult == true && getEmail()==AdminTest()){
          // if the sender has the proper admin email / phone #, then call function sendEmails
          sendEmails();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```